# Jquery change opacity level randomly to many images

Tags: jquery, html

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
<a href=""><img class="fade" src="img.jpg" /></a>
<a href=""><img class="fade" src="img.jpg" /></a>
<a href=""><img class="fade" src="img.jpg" /></a>
<a href=""><img class="fade" src="img.jpg" /></a>
<a href=""><img class="fade" src="img.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

and I'm trying to make and effect with jquery so that the opacity of every image is adjusted randomly to any opacity level (simulating a fade out but not entirely) and back to 1 (simulating a fadein) on an infinite loop and randomly

I want to do it randomly with every image

I was trying to tweak this jquery lines

```
    (function fadeInDiv() {
    var divs = $j('.fade');
    var elem = divs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length));
    if (!elem.is(':visible')) {
        elem.prev().remove();
        elem.fadeIn(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), fadeInDiv);
    } else {

        elem.fadeOut(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), function() {
            elem.before('<img>');
            fadeInDiv();
        });
    }
})();
```

to accomplish that but I wasn't able to get it to work (i'm not a jquery pro so i'm a little in a dead end here.) I tried to add

`.fadeTo('slow', 0.1);` and `.fadeTo('slow', 1);`

But it didn't do anything. Is there anyway to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are causing max-call stack exceeded error due to the recursive call to `fadeInDiv();` in your fadeOut. Use a callback to make the recursive call something like using `window.setTimeout`.

```
else {

        elem.fadeOut(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), function() {
            elem.before('<img>');
            window.setTimeout(fadeInDiv); //<-- Here
            //fadeInDiv();
        });
    }
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c3zDK/)

To animate opacity you can try this:-

```
//Code
elem.animate({
         opacity: (Math.random() * 1)
     }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), function () {
         elem.before('<img>');
         window.setTimeout(fadeInDiv);
         //fadeInDiv();
     });
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xHthT/)

Comment: ok, is there a way to make it fade to a random opacity level instead of completly fading out? I don't want the images to disapear just get the opacity level adjusted.

Comment: @Gman In that case you should use animate instead of fadein/fadeout.

Comment: my hero exactly what I wanted to do!! thanks and sorry for the dumb question I'm just not a pro with jquery